# Can`t crawl web site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl , but i have some troubles in it, i need to open every link of the good and get information of it and save it in .html every good at the page
for now i can only print all links on the page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests
import urllib3
import ssl
from requests import request

urllib3.disable_warnings()

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
        pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
t = request('GET', url=my_url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": 'product'})

filename = "web.html"
f= open(filename, "w")

for containers in page_soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'product'}):
    f.write(containers.a['href'] + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Let's start with this: why are you making two of the same request? Just to see how it works? I'm not seeing you use `t` after you make that request.

Comment: t is for ssl verification, i can delete 1 of them for sure, thats nvm, i cant find every good at all pages and scrap all info by links

Comment: So far you write a list of all the URLs. Please [edit] your question to show what information you are trying to get from each of these URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to get a list of URLs from a first URL and then wanting to get some information from each of these URLs. To do this, a request for each URL needs to be made and a separate BeautifulSoup parse is needed for each.

Once you have the sub page, information can then be extracted, for example the name of the product and its price.

Finally you could either print this information or write it to a file. The easiest way is to write it as a CSV file. In this example I show how you could write the URL and name and the price as a single row. The CSV library automatically formats correctly:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
my_url = 'https://franke-market.com.ua/moyki.html?on_page=100'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
req = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

with open("products.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['URL', 'Title', 'Price'])

    # Find the URLs for all the products
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'product'})[:5]:
        url = div.a['href']
        print(url)

        # For each URL, get the sub page and get the name and price
        req_sub = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        soup_sub = BeautifulSoup(req_sub.content, "html.parser")        
        title = soup_sub.find('h1', class_='title').text
        price_info = soup_sub.find('div', class_='price_info').span.text

        # Write the url, name and price as a CSV file
        csv_output.writerow([url, title, price_info])
```

Giving you and `output.csv` file starting:

```
URL,Title,Price
https://franke-market.com.ua/franke_rol_610-38_101_0267_707_.html,Franke ROL 610-38 (101.0267.707),91795
https://franke-market.com.ua/franke-pmn-611i-101.0255.790.html,Franke Pamira PMN 611i (101.0255.790),57935
https://franke-market.com.ua/franke_pxl_611-60_101_0330_655_.html,Franke PXL 611-60 (101.0330.655),93222
https://franke-market.com.ua/franke-ron-610-41-101.0255.783.html,Franke Ron 610-41 (101.0255.783),57939
https://franke-market.com.ua/franke_pxl_611-78_101_0330_657_.html,Franke PXL 611-78 (101.0330.657),93223
```

You could then open this file into a spreadsheet application.